# How to convert Spring Integration XML to Java DSL

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have the below xml configuration in my application and I would like to convert it to the Java DSL.

```xml
<int:chain
    input-channel="preparedOrder-InputChannelTransformer"
    output-channel="preparedOrder-OutputChannel">
    <int:json-to-object-transformer
        type="service.prepareOrder.PreparedOrder" />
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="messageID"
            expression="headers['id'].toString()" />
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int:filter expression="payload.delay &lt; 5" />
</int:chain>
<int:chain input-channel="preparedOrder-OutputChannel"
    output-channel="billingServiceAcivatorOutput"
    id="service-activator-chain-billingChannel-id">
    <int:service-activator
        id="service-activator-billingChannel-id">
        <int-script:script lang="js"
            location="file:src/main/orcha/service/billing/billing.js" />
        <int:request-handler-advice-chain />
    </int:service-activator>
</int:chain>
<int:transformer
    id="transformer-billingServiceAcivatorOutput-id"
    input-channel="billingServiceAcivatorOutput"
    output-channel="billingAggregatorInput" method="transform">
    <bean
        class="orcha.lang.compiler.referenceimpl.xmlgenerator.impl.ObjectToApplicationTransformer">
        <property name="application" ref="billing" />
    </bean>
</int:transformer>
<int:aggregator id="aggregator-billingAggregatorInput-id"
    input-channel="billingAggregatorInput"
    output-channel="billingAggregatorInputTransformer"
    release-strategy-expression="size()==1 and ( ([0].payload instanceof T(orcha.lang.configuration.Application) AND [0].payload.state==T(orcha.lang.configuration.State).TERMINATED) )"
    correlation-strategy-expression="headers['messageID']" />
<int:transformer
    id="transformer-billingAggregatorInput-id"
    input-channel="billingAggregatorInputTransformer"
    output-channel="billingAggregatorInputAggregatorOutput"
    expression="payload.?[name=='billing']" />
<int:transformer
    id="transformer-billingAggregatorInputAggregatorOutput-id"
    input-channel="billingAggregatorInputAggregatorOutput"
    output-channel="billingAggregatorOutputTransformer" method="transform">
    <bean
        class="orcha.lang.compiler.referenceimpl.xmlgenerator.impl.ApplicationToObjectTransformer" />
</int:transformer>
<int:chain input-channel="billingAggregatorOutputTransformer"
    output-channel="billingOutputFileChannelAdapteraccounting">
    <int:object-to-json-transformer />
</int:chain>
<int:channel id="billingOutputFileChannelAdapteraccounting" />
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="file-billingaccountingChannel-id"
    channel="billingOutputFileChannelAdapteraccounting"
    directory-expression="@accounting.output.adapter.directory"
    filename-generator-expression="@accounting.output.adapter.filename"
    append-new-line="true" mode="REPLACE" auto-create-directory="true"
    delete-source-files="false" />
```

Comment: Hi what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```java
@Bean
IntegrationFlow flow() {
    IntegrationFlows.from("preparedOrder-InputChannelTransformer")
        .transform(Transformers.fromJson())
        .enrichHeaders(...)
        .handle(...)
        .transform(objToAppTransformer())
        .aggregate(...)
        .transform("payload.?[name=='billing']")
        .transform(appToObjTransformer())
        .transform(Transformers.toJson())
        .handle(files.outboundAdapter(...))
        .get();
}
```